# Correct Key for Microsoft Cognitive API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am currently trying to do a News Search on the MS Cognitive Services Bing Search API. I have read many docs, but seem to be stuck.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$url = 'https://bingapis.azure-api.net/api/v5/news/search?q=microsoft&mkt=en-us';
$key = '{MY KEY}';
$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: '. $key;
$request_headers[] = 'User-Agent: mozilla';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

This code returns the following result:

```
{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }
```

As I get the same result from the API Explorer on the site, I think the problem is with my key, rather than my code. But this is the key supplied by Cognitive Services for my subscription, as found on https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/subscriptions (when logged in).

If this is not the correct key, what should I be using?

Comment: Having the exact issue with the search API. Hoping it resolves itself soon.

Comment: Please make sure that you substitute `{MY KEY}` with your key, and make certain to remove the curly braces.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft's API Explorer with the key they generated and only receiving 401s. I think this is an issue on Microsoft's side.

Comment: What do you mean by the API Explorer?

Comment: "API Testing Console". Microsoft's official way to test your API key and play around: https://bingapis.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/56b4433fcf5ff8098cef380c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm on the Cognitive Service team at Microsoft. You may hit this issue for the Bing APIs if you generated your subscription keys after 22 June (or renewed your key) and are currently using the https://bingapis.azure-api.net/api/v5/ base URI.

When updating to use the new subscription keys, you must update your application to use the https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/ base URI.

Additionally, If you were using the API Reference for Bing APIs, you can try the following links below which should work with the new keys.

Apologies for the inconvenience and thanks for reporting the issue- we are getting the link updated.

Comment: Image: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/571fab09dbe2d933e891028f 

Video: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f3ccf5ff8098cef3809/operations/56b440d2cf5ff8098cef380b

Comment: Here are the API Reference Links

WebSearch: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d 

AutoSuggest: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56c7694ecf5ff801a090fbd1/operations/56c769a2cf5ff801a090fbd2

Comment: News: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f72cf5ff8098cef380a/operations/56f02400dbe2d91900c68553 

SpellCheck: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56e73033cf5ff80c2008c679/operations/56e73036cf5ff81048ee6727

Comment: SpellCheck: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56e73033cf5ff80c2008c679/operations/56e73036cf5ff81048ee6727 

See more info here as well:
https://msdnstage.redmond.corp.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn760794.aspx

Comment: It'd be much appreciated if you guys change the URL in the cURL example:
https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/GetStarted/GetStarted-cURL

Comment: I am getting this error with the Azure Logic App connectors which is kind of ironic.