# Microsoft Bing Speech API: Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I tried to issue token for voice recognition request as in Microsoft Cognitive Services [Bing Speech API tutorial](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/api-reference-rest/bingvoicerecognition) from Postman:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF5Ht.png)

Input URL encoded string is:

```
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[my_key]&client_secret=[my_key]&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fspeech.platform.bing.com
```

And API responds with error:

```
{
   "statusCode": 401,
   "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription."
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I saw the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969050/correct-key-for-microsoft-cognitive-api), but I don't see update about Bing Speech API in answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you have three issues:

1. The request needs to contain a `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header
2. Your body has an extraneous '=' at the beginning (corrected above)
3. Your URL appears to be double-encoded, so instead of https:%3A... you have https:%253A... (corrected above)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, you are right. I've corrected input string. But the response is still the same.

Comment: And for `my_key` you're using the key under Speech - Preview at the https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-US/subscriptions page?

Comment: Yes. And I've tried both of the keys under Speech - Preview - the result is the same. The keys were generated after 22 of June.

Comment: My bad - you're also missing the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header.  The header value should be your API key.

Comment: Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key is the key you need to add in header for successful request